# How do I change the label in a view controller I want to load a tableviewcell is selected?

Tags: swift

When a user taps a row I want to go to a view controller which will have the name of that selected row as the label text.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let pvc = segue.destination as! ProfileViewController
    let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    
    if let unwrappedPath = indexpath {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: unwrappedPath, animated: true)
        pvc.profileName.text = userList[unwrappedPath.row]

    }  
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToProfile", sender: self)

    
}
```

line 66 is this code: **pvc.profileName.text = userList[unwrappedPath.row]**
the text property of pic.profileName.text is nil at this point even though I assigned the string at userList path to the label's text property.

Console:

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file (filenamegoeshere)/FoundTableViewController.swift, line 66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference a view (`profileName`) that has not already been instantiated.

You should declare a global variable in `ProfileViewController` like this

```
var expectedString = ""
```

and edit your `prepare(for segue: ...)` method like this

```
    guard let pvc = segue.destination as? ProfileViewController else { return }
    let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    
    if let unwrappedPath = indexpath {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: unwrappedPath, animated: true)
        pvc.expectedString = userList[unwrappedPath.row]
    }
```

Then you can set your label text in the `viewWillAppear` method of the `ProfileViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    profileName.text = expectedString
}
```

Comment: much appreciated!